# Ubuntu 12.04 root user changes

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I accidental switched my user account from administrator to standard user, now I can't enjoy the root previllages in ubuntu 12.04 how do I change back to admin

Comment: Another one good question for superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You must login as Root user, and than edit the user account privileges.
The password of the Root account is setted by you on system installation.

Comment: how can I login as root and the user account has been change to standard?

Comment: on login screen insert "root" username and the password you choosed on installation process

Comment: I think that also this guide could be helpful for you: 
http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/05/login-as-root-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Comment: @MichaelLesaloi was it helpful?

Comment: on current workstation, open terminal and run su root